# Why does my twitter bot only tweet one word or letter, and not a full sentence?

Tags: python, twitter

I have coded the random sentence generator, which works. However, when it sends out the tweet, it only tweets one word or one letter. I do not really know what's going on. Here is the code for the sentence and for tweeting:

```
#random sentence generator
with open("Hannibal.txt") as f:
    words = f.read().split()

word_dict = defaultdict(list)
for word, next_word in zip(words, words[1:]):
    word_dict[word].append(next_word)

word = "Hannibal"

while not word.endswith("."):
    print(word, end=" ")
    word = random.choice(word_dict[word])
    if len(word) > 50:
        word = word[-5:]
print(word)

#this bit is supposed to tweet the random sentence.
for i in word:
    try:
        print("Status Updated!")
        print(word)
        api.update_status(i)
        time.sleep(1200)
    except tweepy.TweepError as e:
        print(e.reason)
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

This is what prints out when I run code.

#first the sentence:
Hannibal was lost, besides, in places of his own sons in charge of the soldiers now pervaded the walls to give rise, deprive ambitious of various parts of Hannibal in Italy, but he had to say that he carried, with his colleague like to allow their opinion of those of the wrath of age, on all that ensued lasted seventeen years, the Carthaginians were willing to avoid the hostages or closed, and true to them battle.

#Then this notice:
Status Updated!

#Finally this which is just the last word of the sentence:
battle.

The tweet is just the first letter of that word.

[here is what is tweeted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnEEV.jpg)

Comment: What do you expect this line of code to do? `word_dict = defaultdict(list)`

Comment: That is just part of the random sentence generator. that part of the code works. its part of this `from collections import defaultdict`

Comment: the sentences aren't supposed to make much sense by the way. For some reason I find it really funny.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are overwriting your "word" variable every time you add a new random word:

```
word = random.choice(word_dict[word])
```

Instead you should do something like

```
sentence = []
word = "Hannibal"
while not word.endswith("."):
    sentence.append(word)
    word = random.choice(word_dict[word])
    ...
sentence = " ".join(sentence)
```